# What is the proper way to add an Xcode project and any 3rd party frameworks to a remote repository?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6.1

I'm running into an issue with importing a 3rd party framework in **Xcode 6.1** using **Swift**.

I followed the steps below to add the framework:

```
1. cd into the project directory. 
2. git submodule add git://repo.com/example3rdPartyFramework.git
3. add the example3rdPartyFramework.xcodeproj file to my Xcode project through Xcode.
4. Modify my project Build Phase accordingly
```

I'm able to successfully build and run the project. After pushing the changes, including the 3rd party framework to my remote repository, I do the following on a different machine:

```
git clone --recursive git://repo.com/myProject.git
```

It adds everything including the 3rd party framework submodule. However, I go to build my project and get the error: **'No such module xxxxxx'**.

So I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong, if anything?

Comment: http://cocoapods.org release 0.36 supports swift and frameworks

Comment: @bensarz unfortunately, this particular framework does not work with Cocoapods

Comment: well a really good exercise for anyone to do would be to create your own podspec file for it, you don't even need to fork it if you don't want to but it would be easier to fork it and add your podspec file to it.

Comment: start here: http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html

Comment: @bensarz, I totally agree, however the project author already stated the incompatibility of his framework as found here https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/issues/44 . Perhaps I'll have to go with a different option as this issue may be specific to the framework.

Comment: well this is not great, you could use git submodules or git subtree, great article: http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/